# LINQ distinct and sorting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, .net-7.0

I have the following query, which I wish to be distinct on "RegistrationNumber", and sorted by "DriverToLoad".

Distinct/grouping works fine. However, my query sorts by "RegistrationNumber" apparently ignoring the "OrderBy":

```
            Drive = await _db.Drive
                .Where(m => m.StatusId == 5 || m.StatusId == 1010 || m.StatusId == 1012)
                .Include(s => s.DriveStatus)
                .Include(d => d.Location)
                .Include(f => f.Item)
                .GroupBy(m => m.RegistrationNumber)
                .Select(g => g.OrderBy(m => m.DriverToLoad).First())
                .ToListAsync(),
```

Any LINQ experts who can point out what the problem is, and how to solve it?
I'm working with .NET7.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What type is `DriverToLoad`?

Comment: DriveToLoad is DateTime

Comment: You are grouping by `RegistrationNumber` which will also sort by `RegistrationNumber`,  then for each group returning the row with the earliest `DriverToLoad` so, later rows in each group will be discarded. The results will appear to be sorted by `RegistrationNumber`.

Comment: Hard to know what you want to happen, unless you tell  us.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest you want something like this:

```
var Drive =
    await _db.Drive
        .Where(m => m.StatusId == 5 || m.StatusId == 1010 || m.StatusId == 1012)
        .Include(s => s.DriveStatus)
        .Include(d => d.Location)
        .Include(f => f.Item)
        .GroupBy(m => m.RegistrationNumber, m => m.DriverToLoad)
        .SelectMany(g => g.OrderBy(x => x).Take(1))
        .ToListAsync();
```

Or like this:

```
var Drive =
    await
    (
        from m in _db.Drive
            .Include(s => s.DriveStatus)
            .Include(d => d.Location)
            .Include(f => f.Item)
        where m.StatusId == 5 || m.StatusId == 1010 || m.StatusId == 1012
        group m.DriverToLoad by m.RegistrationNumber into g
        from d in g.OrderBy(x => x).Take(1)
        select d
    )
        .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I've tried your first one, and I'm getting a cast error, and I now see that DriverToLoad is a nullable DateTime. Maybe that is not a good idea (even though I need it to be)?

Comment: @RenéWester - And that's why you should post a [mcve] with your code. It's a waste of time otherwise.

Comment: @Enigamativity: I agree, sorry about that. I'll remember that next time. Thanks anyway for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it, but probably not the nicest way (...more like a "hack" I would say).

```
        var drive = await _db.Drive
        .Where(m => m.StatusId == 5 || m.StatusId == 1010 || m.StatusId == 1012)
        .Include(s => s.DriveStatus)
        .Include(d => d.Location)
        .Include(f => f.Item)
        .GroupBy(m => m.RegistrationNumber)
        .Select(g => g.OrderBy(m => m.DriverToLoad).First())
        .ToListAsync();

        DriveListViewModel model = new DriveListViewModel()
        {
            Drive = drive.OrderBy(a => a.DriverToLoad),
        };
```

This way I get the sorting I wish, and can return that to the view.

Haven't yet seen the power of LINQ, so maybe I should aim for using ADO and SQL directly in my controllers, and somehow convert that to lists to be returned to my views ;-)

Thank you all for all your great suggestions. I really appreciate it.

Comment: If you are ok with `Drive` being `IEnumerable` - you can remove `await` and change `ToListAsync` to `AsEnumerable`